# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in wl_cart_table.php

Tags: woocommerce

I am sorry I don't know the coding yet I am a WordPress frontend designer. I am facing an error:

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/u623573559/domains/infantoutlet.com.pk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woolentor-addons-pro/includes/addons/wl_cart_table.php on line 1307
```

Is there anything wrong with 1307 line?

```
$price = round( $pre_price * ( 1 - ($data['discount_amount']/100) ), 2 );
```

The Full Code:

```
/**
 * [apply_discount]
 * @param  [array] $threshold Discount data array
 * @param  [array] $cart_item cart data
 * @return [int]   price
 */
public function apply_discount( $threshold, $cart_item ){

    $pre_price = $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
    foreach ( $threshold as $key => $data ) {
        if( $cart_item['quantity'] >= $data['discount_qtn'] ){
            if( $data['discount_type'] === 'amount' ){
                $price = $pre_price - ( $data['discount_amount'] / $cart_item['quantity'] );
            }else{
                $price = round( $pre_price * ( 1 - ($data['discount_amount']/100) ), 2 );
            }
        }
    }
    return $price;
```

Comment: It looks like your $data array has something that’s not a number in it.  Have you looked at your $data to see what’s in it?  I would start there.

Comment: This is a bug that comes from WooLentor Elementor Addon Pro premium plugin, so you should ask on their dedicated support, as StackOverFlow doesn't handle any software support.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in PHP 7.1, a Warning will be emitted if a non-numeric value is encountered. See this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.other-changes.php).

Here is the relevant portion that pertains to the Warning notice you are getting:

> New E_WARNING and E_NOTICE errors have been introduced when invalid
> strings are coerced using operators expecting numbers or their
> assignment equivalents. An E_NOTICE is emitted when the string begins
> with a numeric value but contains trailing non-numeric characters, and
> **an E_WARNING is emitted when the string does not contain a numeric
> value.**

I'm guessing **$data['discount_amount']** does not contain a numeric value, so make sure that they do before trying to use them. Maybe use some sort of conditional before calculating the $sub_total, like so:

```
<?php
    $discount = isset($data['discount_amount']) && isnumeric($data['discount_amount']) ? $data['discount_amount'] : 0;
    $price = round( $pre_price * ( 1 - $discount ), 2 );
```